# What changes were made to Maersk blue?

Tags: colour

I [read](https://web.archive.org/web/20111124195833/http://www.tabletownonline.com/glossaryb.php) that LEGO recently changed the colour of Maersk blue. Is this true? If so, why did they make a change?

Comment: I was a part of this team that worked on the project. I’ll get some notes together in regards to the colors, the changes, the decisions behind making the changes, etc.. A couple of the answers above were very good, actually. Is there a way to post on here some of our original notes from the project? I would be happy to share. Tks, Dav

Comment: Hi @davis-lipis and welcome to Bricks. No worries with the previous post - would be very happy for you to share what you know, and more than happy to help you out. We do provide image hosting here on StackExchange, however I think you need at least 10 reputation to add them initially. If you Edit your answer with as much detail as you can, and if possible/needed a link or two to some images I'm sure one of us can edit them inline for you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Considering that color has been produced explicitely and exclusively for Maersk sets, it's highly unlikely they would change it. Most people seem to [agree](http://www.fbtb.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=5130#p52289) that the same color has been used for all Maersk ships sets.

That said, you'll also need to consider that even if LEGO never intended to change the color, small variations in hue are always possible (red and purple are much more susceptible to this). Also, in the case of Maersk, LEGO used their entire supply in 2006 and said at the time that they wouldn't issue Maersk sets again because of that. However, Maersk realized the demand was high (LEGO did consider making a version fo the ships in another color altogether at some point) and agreed to have LEGO make a new batch to later on. So these are in effect different batches, separated by a few years, which means any hue change will be more likely to be noticed than if it appeared gradually over time.