# How to sell massive, vintage and unsorted lego collection with manuals?

Tags: shopping, instructions, organisation, trading

So I was a big LEGO collector as a child in the early 1990s. The genres I have are town/city, pirates, and castle. To store them, I broke them all down to fit into 2 giant plastic tubs. I still have virtually all of the instruction booklets/foldouts that came with the LEGOS, and a few of the boxes as well. Some big sets, particularly the pirate ships and castles.

My question is how to go about selling them. Should I sort them? I've tried to pull the figures/accessories out, but otherwise it's overwhelming! I was pretty careful as a kid and didn't lose much, but it's hard to say how complete everything is just by looking (90-95% I guess).

I was thinking of listing the sets and their manuals in there and taking photos as best as possible (especially of the figs). Any suggestion where to sell them online?

Apologies for the long post.

Comment: Similar to [How should I go about selling $3k worth of unsorted LEGO sets?](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/1160/789)

Answer (score 8):

Depending on what you have, your best bet is probably to re-build each set, and sell them as complete.  Try [BrickLink](http://www.bricklink.com/) if you're not in a hurry to sell.  You can see how much sets are selling for, and price yours accordingly.  You can list them until they sell, and they only charge a small percentage when the items sell.  If you want fast cash, sell them on eBay.

These two sites will get you the most bang for your bricks.

Answer (score 1):

Zapper buy unsorted Lego. As of today (July 2016) they pay £3.50 per kilo. Can be sold in 0.5kg increments but you need £10 minimum worth of trade before you can send it off but this can be made up of books, DVDs etc. all in the same package.

Comment: Do you have a link?