# Value/Where to sell my old Lego collection

Tags: shopping

I'm sure you've heard this asked a million times but I have no idea where and for what price I should be selling my old collection for.

Things I do know about what I have:

- I'd assume they're "clean" (no dirt or wear, right?)
- Weighs right around 85lbs for everything
- Contained into two boxes, ~50lbs/~30lbs
- A lot of figurines from various places, I'm unsure if they have value.
- I have this thing and a train set: [Train Switch](http://www.brickpicker.com/bpms/set.cfm?set=4548-1)
- Some soccer field like set with parts, balls, and players.
- Sets: 3826, 6211, 7621, 4956, 6206, 10176
- There's more sets than I know of, those are only the ones I brought out and remembered.

[Images of Lego](https://imgur.com/a/Tcq7v#ELXLiVA)
- the last two images are of RokenBlok, if you knew anywhere I could sell those as well it'd be a lot of help.

*Where would you price this? I'm in no rush to sell it, but I'm going off to college so unless it was particular reason to fish a set out, I'd sell in bulk for reasonable prices. If you need any more information please ask.*

Comment: possible duplicate: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1578/how-to-sell-massive-vintage-and-unsorted-lego-collection-with-manuals

Comment: I would sell it on Bricklink, but if you need alot of money, go on ebay or amazon.

Comment: Another possible duplicate: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/9716/56

Answer (score 6):

Generally, I see LEGO collections like this sold by the pound.  I don't generally pay more than $8/lb (including shipping, if applicable) on large used lots, because they are rarely 100% clean, like-new condition LEGO bricks.  Most collections include poor quality pieces, as well as many non-LEGO brand and non-LEGO-compatible toys that have somehow been thrown in.

If you guarantee 100% clean, like-new condition LEGO pieces, the price would go up to maybe $12/pound.  However, in my experience, very few collections that have actually been played with will meet this standard.  Play wear isn't terrible, but it's definitely not like-new.

In the US, eBay is a common way to sell.  You might also try Craigslist to avoid the shipping hassle.

Some items are more valuable and are worth selling separately. In particular, train components and licensed minifigures (like Star Wars, Spiderman, Avengers, etc.) are probably worth the time and hassle.  Other minifigures (like town, space, western, etc) I would just include with the bulk lot, as separating those out and selling them individually will be a lot of work for minimal gain.

If you really want top dollar and are willing to put your time time, the best way is to probably start a BrickLink store, and sell all the parts individually.  This might be a great opportunity to start a side business.  It will, however, require you to inventory your entire collection, as well as manage the shipping, customer challenges, etc.

Good luck with selling your collection!

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I have sold my LEGO sets on Craigslist and eBay. I also sold them at a garage sale.

The LEGO had some use tear-and-wear, but they only were Lego, and I cleaned and sorted them into boxes. I sold it at $10 per lbs, but I gave them free shipping, handling, and 1-2 business days.

I used United States Postal Service to ship it to them. I sold 100 lbs in total, and buyers who came back to me got a free pound of Lego pieces.

I used this for [disinfecting](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00IB18VPG) wipes to clean them and a [LEGO 2-Piece Sorting Divider Set](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008M9X1W0) for storage.