# What's the fastest way to rebuild different sets that have been brought together

Tags: building, star-wars, disassembly

My mom did something to my LEGO. When I was a kid I loved playing with them. Frankly I have no interest in it anymore.  She broke down all them sets, and put them all in a huge box.

I still can figure out some parts, but I don't know if it's better to break down every piece and rebuild from scratch.  I'm not talking about 3 or 4 sets, more like 20 to 30 LEGO sets worth around 3k to 4k euro...  I want to resell it, sadly she took away the building books and the boxes and did them away too.

Comment: Some people in this forum are very good at identifying sets. Add some photos of your LEGO and I am sure that at least some set numbers will be found. Then you can use a part list, e.g. on Bricklink, to collect the pieces of the sets.

Comment: Could you clarify if you need to identify some of the sets, or if you want some help to separate the piece of each set, because manual instructions should have at the end a list of all the pieces.

Comment: I can identify them myself, just looking for the best and fastest way to rebuild them. I already seperated pieces by color. Right now I rebuilded the smallest thing I had because it was near completion anyway. Anyhow I see I miss a few things though, bobba fett's helmet for example. I was wondering if there is some place where I can buy these spare parts too

Comment: Related: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1160/how-should-i-go-about-selling-a-large-number-of-unsorted-lego-sets

Comment: So you have all parts and instructions in front of you and your question now is how to assemble the pieces as fast as possible?? Without interest in LEGO, as you mentioned, I would use Bricklink to collect the pieces of each set, put them in bags, take product photos and sell them separately on Ebay.

Answer (score 4):

In order to gain value out of this, you're going to have to put some work in.

Start with the largest sized kit that you remember doing and assemble the parts (find the building instructions online).  Then move onto the next smallest, and so on.

Obviously, you're not going to remember the details of all the kits you had, but the largest ones should be more memorable (and usually they're worth more).

Comment: I like this plan, but I actually think it would be easier to start with the smaller sets and build-up to the larger sets.

Comment: Easier, yes.  But if in doing so, you take parts away from the larger sets, you're implicitly losing money on resale (which is what the OP is attempting to do).  I'm just recommending a way of getting the maximum value out of that box of bits.

Comment: That makes sense too.  I figured he'd be buying missing parts on bricklink anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Without the instructions it's going to be hard to reconstruct the sets and it will reduce the price anyway (I think people who cares for old sets also want the instructions). But you can find many instructions online.

Your valuation of 100-200€/set is probably unrealistic. There are lots of sets in that price range, but they are fairly large (especially in the upper end), so it doesn't sound like a typical kid collection, and when you include that it's used without boxes or instructions it becomes even more unrealistic.

I would need to see the parts to give a real recommendation, if it's all (but it has to be quite close) bigger parts that are reasonably easy to connect I would try that, but you easily end up spending more time looking at the model to find out where some small piece goes.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I have begun rebuilding a bit of small sets. Reason why I try to look at the price is because these sets already cost that much in the store. I have a huge collection of lego star wars, with a lot of big sets.